# Cross compiling driver for mips

Tags: driver, mips, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a simple driver example for a mips device. The driver is really just a test:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

int ath_pci_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "alive and hacked\n");
    return 0;
}

void ath_pci_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "dead and hacked\n");
}

module_init (ath_pci_init);
module_exit (ath_pci_exit);
```

And compiles using this Makefile:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := driver.o
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/3.2.0-81-generic/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

For x86 works perfectly. For mips, I tried changing the Makefile to:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := driver.o
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/3.2.0-81-generic/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=~/Downloads/openwrt2/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc- M=$(PWD) modules

endif
```

but it does not work.
Following a sugestion I saw I used the first Makefile but instead of running `make default` I ran:

```
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=~/openwrt2/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc- default
```

In both cases, I get this:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-81-generic/build M=<folder> modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/alchemy/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/ar7/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/ath79/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/bcm47xx/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/bcm63xx/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/cavium-octeon/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/cobalt/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/dec/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/emma/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/jazz/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/jz4740/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/lantiq/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/lasat/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/loongson/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/mipssim/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/mti-malta/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/netlogic/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/pmc-sierra/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/pnx833x/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/pnx8550/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/powertv/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/rb532/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/sgi-ip22/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/sgi-ip27/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/sgi-ip32/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/sibyte/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/sni/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/txx9/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/vr41xx/Platform: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/Kbuild.platforms:35: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/wrppmc/Platform: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic/arch/mips/wrppmc/Platform'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-81-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I am guessing that by redirecting the CC to the toolchain, I have to provide it with the same resources (or equivalent) as the native compiler. However, I have no clue on how to do this.

How can I compile my driver?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to cross-compile a driver you also need a cross-compiled prepared kernel, and a valid configuration file for the kernel.

You have to download the kernel against you want to compile the driver, then run:

```
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc- oldconfig
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc- prepare
```

then update the makefile to use this kernel, something like:

```
KERNELDIR ?= <path to kernel>/kernel/3.2.0-81-generic/
```